# Change value of button in an UITableViewCell is changing other button value

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

If Too long, my problem is : When i click on the play of button of a cell and want to change the image of the pressed play button, some other cell's play button change too.

I'm creating an app where you can get Music preview and play them. 
To display this, I use an `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell` containing a play button and some other things.

That's how it's looking.

[image]

So when i click on a Cell Play button, the right track is played but here's the problem : I try to change the backgroundImage of my button but other buttons image are changed too... And if I scroll my button even get back to the image it was using before I make the change...

[image: The cell correctly shows the new image]
The cell correctly shows the new image
[image: But some other do it too...]
But some other do it too...
[image]
And if I scroll up, my new image is remplaced by the older one...

Here's my function code :

```
func getPreview(sender : AnyObject){

    var positionButton = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.feedTable)
    var indexPath = self.feedTable.indexPathForRowAtPoint(positionButton)
    var rowIndex = indexPath!.row

    var cell = feedTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
    var bouton: UIButton = cell?.valueForKey("postPlay") as! UIButton



    if sender.title == "Mettre l'extrait en pause" {
        mediaPlayer.pause()
        sender.setTitle("Jour l'extrait", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        var playImage = UIImage(named: "playIcon")
        sender.setImage(playImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    if rowIndex == bouton.tag{
        var songLink = post[rowIndex].valueForKey("previewLink") as! String
        let url = NSURL(string: songLink)

        mediaPlayer.contentURL = url
        mediaPlayer.play()

        bouton.setTitle("Mettre l'extrait en pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        var pauseImage = UIImage(named: "pauseIcon")
        bouton.setImage(pauseImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }


}
```

Could you help me to find what's wrong ? Thank you !

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Pictures can be helpful, but I've missed the problem here.  This is just a wall of pictures.  What's wrong with the code exactly?  What behavior are you getting?  What behavior are you expecting?  How do these differ?

Comment: Edited, i put a short version at the start of my message. Sorry i'm belgian so I try to explain the best I can with my english...

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCells are reused, not stored offscreen until you need one for the same index path again. So each time a cell is displayed, `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, and you're responsible for completely setting up the cell. Every time. You can't assume a state you've previously set up for a cell at that index path is still intact.

Comment: So there's nothing I can do ?

Comment: Theres never nothing you can do. "you're responsible for completely setting up the cell. Every time. You can't assume a state you've previously set up for a cell at that index path is still intact." You can go make your datasource keep track of what image should go to what cell and use that in cellForRowAtIndexPath